# How to create default web site in iis 7 server?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web

I am new to ASP.Net.
     I have deleted `Default website` in accidentally. How to create Default Web site in IIS 7?

Comment: Related [Recreate the default website in IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750632/1577396)

Comment: Go through this [`link`](http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2005/12/09/62737.aspx) too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Uninstall the Windows Process Activation Service feature(the dependent package for the IIS feature package) before reinstall the IIS. Then you will be able retrieve the Default Web Site.