# Recreate Default Website in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-6

I've had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750632/recreate-the-default-website-in-iis), but when I've created the website I need to know what user to use for the pass-through authentication:

[image: Adding Default Website]

Looking at wwwroot in File Explorer, I can see it has `IIS_IUSERS`, which I tried giving full control to.  I assume that the solution isn't to give it my admin account as authentication.

Before I deleted it, it was fine, so what have I missed?  Maybe the original Default Website didn't use pass-through Authentication or maybe I'm missing something else.

What's the *correct* solution?