# IIS showing iisstart page instead of my application page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I deployed an ASP.Net application on the ISS which is located in a local network. After that, I just right clicked to my web site if it is working and I saw that it is working but when I try to access to this page from my PC I got iisstart.html (default IIS page). Do you know how can I solve this issue?

What I did up to now:

- I check the default document and I removed issstart.html definition
  from there
- I removed also this file from wwwroot folder.

[image]

Comment: Stop default iis site and clear browsing history and cache, try to access your site with 80 port binding.

Answer (score 1):

Change port number of website in iis

Comment: It did not work, it is same I changed it as 5500. Beside that, I want to use default 80 port.

Comment: Kindly refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750632/recreate-the-default-website-in-iis

Comment: did the job champ!