# Unable to create the virtual directory. The web server 'http://localhost/foo' could not be found

Tags: .net, iis, visual-studio-2015, virtual-directory

I have created a demo project in VS 2015 and I tried to create a virtual directory from VS: Right click on project-> properties-> web -> selected local IIS option and click on create virtual directory.

But I am getting this error:

> unable to create the virtual directory. The web server
> http://localhost/MVCDemo" could not be found.

Here are screenshots of the error:

[image: error]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the url of your site in iis?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with VS 2019. Were you able to find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If Visual Studio can't create a virtual directory for your application, chances are there's a mismatch between your project's settings on Visual Studio and its corresponding settings on IIS Manager.

In my particular case I solved this problem by [recreating the default web site on IIS Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750632/recreate-the-default-website-in-iis).

After recreating the default web site on IIS Manager, Visual Studio became once again able to create the virtual directories, and I could then debug the web application with Local IIS.